# delete jquery cookie from other page on button click asp.net mvc

Tags: cookies, jquery-plugins

How can we delete a cookie [jquery plugin cookie $.cookie()] or set it to null on one page from a diff page? I want to delete a cookie on page 2 from page 1 on button click. I tried so many diff ways and I was unsuccessful. please help. is there any work around?

Answer (score 0):

A cookie is not tied to a page. It is stored on the client computer/browser and sent along each request to the server. So if you set it to null on one page it will be deleted and no longer sent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Darin. and thats what i though..but that is not working. I have $.cookie('x',value) on page 2 . from page 1 if i try $.cookie('x',null) it is not changing the cookie value on page 2.

Answer (score 0):

Rather old question, but I found it so....

Make sure to include the path on the Delete to match the one on the Set

```
$.cookie('key', 'value', { path: '/' });
```

....

```
$.cookie('key', null, { path: '/' });
```